# Google Maps API keys not working when uploading to play store

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a release build for an app that got the SHA1 for it and put it into my API Console so I could use Google Maps. This works just fine when I generate the release build in android studio.

However, when uploading it to the Play Store using Googles App signing process, the signing certificate changes, which means I had to add that SHA1 to be used with my API key. I have done this but when I download it from the Play Store, the map is not loading.

Here is what I am referring to. The different colors match up the sha1 fingerprints.

From the API Console:
[image]

From the Play Developer Console of my app:
[image]

Do I have to do something extra in addition to adding the sha1 from Google's signing process to be used with my API key? The package names should be the same, correct?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The issue was something on Google's end. They say that it may take up to 5 minutes for package / cert changes to take effect but this took over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to generate a SHA-1 key using the same Keystore you generated your Signed APK with.

What I like to do is set up a signing config in my app build.gradle file.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Once you've done this you can then go to Gradle tab and run the signing report.

[image: Gradle Signing Report]

Finally you can view your release variant SHA-1 key in the Gradle Console located at the bottom right of your Android Studio.

You can then use this SHA-1 key to restrict your Google Api Key for release.

Comment: I have the release key, but when I upload to the play store using Google's app signing process, it signs my apk with a different certificate. The second picture shows the different certificates. The "upload certificate" is the one frome Android studio, but the "app signing certificate" is the one Google used to sign my app

Comment: The issue was something on Google's end. They say that it may take up to 5 minutes for package / cert changes to take effect but this took over an hour. Thank you for your help though